# Re-weighting a survey after resampling with replacement been already used

Tags: survey, survey-weights, survey-sampling

I'd love to hear some experts' advice on a survey I'm working on.
Let's assume a survey being conducted on a sample of community organizations.

A public database (the sample frame, but almost a census) of over 2,000  institutions was used to produce a stratified sample of 755 organizations. 
Later on, during the pre-test, researchers found that not all the addresses/telephone provided were actually valid for contacting sampled organizations, some duplicates also were identified on the original database. The company then replaced the problematic units withing each stratum through resampling. However, after the survey gets the road, other units were found with similar issues in such a way that from the 755 original draw, only 720 organizations were actually "valid".

Now, with a stratified sample designed to accommodate 755 elements, but with possibly 720 clearly the weight will not match as expected, so what are the possible ways one has to deal with this? I'd really appreciate in-depth comments accompanied with literature indications.

Comment: Welcome to CV! "2,000 thousand" should be read as "2,000" or as "2 million"? You can edit your post by using the "edit" button at the bottom of it.